# mysqli_fetch_row and SELECT COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm running PHP 7.0 and connected to a mysql db with a record matching the query in the below:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'baz'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
print_r($row[0]);
```

Print outputs 1, as expected as there is only one record matching that username.

However, the following function returns false

```
function user_exists(){
$exists_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'baz'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($exists_query);
return ($row[0] == 1) ? True : False;
}
```

But I would expect it to be true. Am I misusing the fetch function?

Comment: In your `php.ini` file ~ `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly does your first print_r statement output?
It should print an array, not an integer.
Your `$row` is an array of arrays.
So `$row[0]` will not be `'1'` but something like `array('1')`.

Comment: When you have basic problems like this, play with `var_dump`. E.g. `var_dump($row)` and `var_dump($row[0])` to see what those variables contain.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because the `$conn` is not accessible. Try this

```
function user_exists(){
    global $conn;
    $exists_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'baz'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($exists_query);
    return ($row[0] == 1) ? True : False;
}
```

Edit:
As mentioned by @trs, you should consider your `$row[0]` output.

Comment: You say `$conn` is not accessible then produce an answer where `$conn` is still not accessible

Comment: I copied the code but while writing the answer, totally forgot to add the `global $conn`. My bad